# Why the difference of rank between these 2 similar matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Why does the matrix

\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} has rank = 2, while this similar-looking (only replaces -1 with 1)   matrix

\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} has rank = 3?

Comment: Because in matrix 1, row 1 plus row 2 plus row 3 equals 0, so there is a nontrivial zero linear combination of the rows of this matrix. Thus it is rank deficient. This is not the case for the second matrix, which does not admit any nontrivial zero linear combinations of its rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, in linear algebra, just because the entries of matrices look similar isn't a good reason to believe they have the same properties. There's kind of no free lunch here. To find the rank, you simply have to go through the row reduction and see for yourself

Comment: Why does $x^2-1=0$ have real roots but $x^2+1=0$ doesn’t? You’ve only replaced $-1$ with $1$, after all. Changing signs is not a *minor* modification.

Comment: Similarity is in the eye of the beholder, I suppose. The first matrix is skew-symmetric but the second is symmetric, so it doesn’t really surprise me that other properties, including rank, might be different, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rank of a matrix is the max. independent column/row vectors.

In the first matrix, clearly, the determinant of $ 3$x$3$ matrix is zero (So, rank$<3 $). So, you've to consider the smaller co-factor matrices for rank determination. Since, there exists atleast one smaller $2$x$2$ which is non-singular (or $ det \ne 0$), rank $=2$.

Whereas, for your second matrix, determinant of $3$x$3$ matrix is non-zero. Hence, rank$=3.$